# _entry.twig in sub folder, rich text editor images using relative URL and are therefore not found

Tags: assets, richtext, siteurl

This may be something obvious that I'm missing, but how can I make craft use absolute URLs for images add to rich text editor fields? Or use the {{siteUrl}} prior to the image src URL in order to fix the issue of images not being found.

Side note - Why are the images not visible within the rich text editor when added? Is this because of the relative URLs too?

Thanks

Comment: It's a bad practice to add or include images in a Rich Text Editor field. Instead of that please use a Asset field. If you find any problem in templating, I would be happy to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the info :) I have since used a matrix field with varying block types for text/images which solved the layout issue of need text then image then text.